# Check SLOC and flag methods over 300 lines long

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way I can configure Visual Studio to automatically scan my source code for methods that are over (eg) 300 lines long so that they can be flagged for review (with an aim to refactoring to smaller methods)

I expect any such technique may be language independant, but ideally I'd like to run this over C# code.

Comment: wtf? what language what everything?

Comment: Point  your finger at the first line.  Say "one".  Point your finger at the second line.  Say "two".  Continue doing this, incrementing the number by one each time until you find yourself saying "three hundred".  Then stop.

Comment: sorry, it's not possible to stop until it's over 9000

Comment: I voted this down because of a complete lack of context to the question. Samael could be talking about a Word doc for all we know.

Comment: Now that Samael has re-edited this, I think it qualifies as a useful question.

Comment: Tools to do this can't be language independent, because each language has a different syntax that needs to be parsed.  However, if you use consistent indentation (or use a [language](http://python.org/) which requires what your coding standards already state), you could get this about halfway done by just looking at that.

Comment: Good edit. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use some code counter tools which you can search in google for.
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=code+counter+tools&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Is there anything specific you are looking for. Why stopping with 300. Are you developing some contest where you would like to restrict people from writing more than 300 lines of code. Anyway be more clear so that we can help you.

I use this one and i find it very useful.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/codecounter.aspx